# How to duplicate the Admin Product template in Opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I have an extension (Quick Update) when installed it overwrite the original product editing page in Admin, and another extension to export products to csv. Im not able to combine the 2 extensions on the same template.

Im using Opencart 2.3.0.2

I want to duplicate the product page, this way Ill have the export csv on 1 page, and Quick Update on another.

Step 1

I duplicated the file admin/conteroller/catalog/product.php

- Changed its name to product1.php
- Changed the class name to ControllerCatalogProduct1
- Changed every catalog/product to catalog/product1

Step 2

I duplicated the file admin/language/en-gb/catalog/product.php

- Changed its name to product1.php
- I don't know if this is a necessary step

Step 3

I duplicated the file admin/model/catalog/product.php

- Changed its name to product1.php
- Changed the class name to ModelCatalogProduct1

Step 4

I duplicated the file admin/view/template/catalog/product.tpl

- Changed its name to product1.tpl
- Changed

From

```
var url = 'index.php?route=catalog/product&token=<?php echo $token; ?>';
```

To

```
var url = 'index.php?route=catalog/product1&token=<?php echo $token; ?>';
```

Step 5

Now I added the new product template to the left column menu and gave permission to the user group.

When I open the page, it's blank. Any help ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

in this file:
admin\controller\catalog\product1.php

Find all:

```
model_catalog_product
```

Replace with:

```
model_catalog_product1
```